# Query time in id lookup Vs index searching

Tags: php, neo4j

i`m developing a social network with php and neo4j
entities like people, company, university have unique addresses like facebook exp: www.network.com/foo-bar
i use foo-bar for index searching and showing the entity

my question is "in 1-3 million nodes on target label how much time and resource will save if i use id lookup in internal links"

to be more clear i can use www.network.com/foo-bar/nodeId when user see foo-bar in recommendation and lookup with id and use index searching only in cases someone want access it via entering address in browser.
but its a little ugly

Answer (score 1):

In general you're right, selecting the node by ID directly is faster than searching the index. But index search is made for the case you described! Make sure you have enough memory and your search should be fast enough to make your URL s look beautiful without speed problems!